# python cffi library object introspection results in __dict__ object change

Tags: python, python-cffi

I would like to get the full listing of enums from the header file using cffi. But I see a strange behaviour: by observing the object, I'm forcing the change in the underlying `__dict__`:

```
>>> from cffi import FFI
>>> ffi = FFI()
>>> ffi.cdef('typedef enum {RANDOM, IMMEDIATE, SEARCH} strategy;')
>>> c = ffi.dlopen('c')

# the dictionary is empty
>>> print c.__dict__
{}

>>> dir(c)

# the dictionary is populated
>>> print c.__dict__
{'SEARCH': 2, 'RANDOM': 0, 'IMMEDIATE': 1}
```

I'm guessing that `__dict__` is not populated until first `getattr()` on the class is called, but the real question is: what does `dir()` do that populates `__dict__`? Calling `hasattr()` seems to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the reason for what you observe is that `dir()` tries to get a few special attributes like `__members__` on the `lib` object.  The code in cffi adds attributes lazily as they are computed.  If a name is not found as a function, it proceeds to install all enums declarations and tries to return one of them if that's the name we try to read.  That's why trying to read a non-existing name will always install all enums in `lib.__dict__`.  (This logic is only for libs returned by `ffi.dlopen()`, not for the API mode.)

Ideally, you should not rely on any of this, but in this case you have to: it is really a bug.  Note that you can simply read `dir(lib)` twice: the second time, it will contain the enum values...
(Fixed the bug in 19cae8d1a5f6: at least `dir(lib)` should always work in cffi 1.4---and no longer list all the special Python method names.)